# to excute a function after 3se

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to reload the page after 3second we visited the page with out repeating

i tried using

```
var t;
t=setTimeout(function(){

     window.location.reload();
},3000);
```

but page is loading continuously

so i tried like this

```
 var t;
 t=setTimeout(function(){
 clearTimeout(t);
           window.location.reload();
 },3000);
```

this trick is also not worked 
can any one help me of how to reload the page after 3second without repeating

Comment: What is the point of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

That is because when the page is reloaded, the script is also reloaded so the browser runs it again. One solution is to use cookie.

```
function SetMeow() {
 var a = new Date();
 a.setTime(a.getTime() + 9999999999999999999);
 document.cookie = "Cat=meow;expires="+a.toGMTString();
}        
var b = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)Cat\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
if(b!="meow"){
var t=setTimeout(function(){
     SetMeow();
     window.location.reload();
},3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a flag, use local storage or cookie, and change when you reload the page once. Or the new interval will be set again everytime the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you refresh a page a completely new page is loaded so you can't actually do that.

In a nutshell you need to save state between pages, this can be done in multiple ways:

- send an AJAX request to some side script
- save state in a Cookie
- use HTML5 LocalStorage

The localStorage one is the easiest:

```
var t = setTimeout (function () {
  if (localStorage.dontReload && JSON.parse(localStorage.dontReload)) { return }
  window.location.reload();
  localStorage.dontReload = true;
}, 3 * 1000);
```

Things to keep in mind about localStorage:

- it only works new relatively new browsers (things older than 2 years
  ago will most likely have issues, but it's not a problem in modern
  browsers)
- it only saves values in string format
- it only saves the values on the current domain so the values will be *local* to the page you're in :)